# How to compose widgets with blaze code in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to write an yesod application without any hamlet parts. My question is about forms: I can generate a form using Applicative, but I cannot use it directly in my blaze code.

Here is a hamlet version example:

```
-- actual form example
userForm :: Form User
userForm = renderDivs $ User
  <$> areq textField "Login" Nothing
-- usage example
getPageR :: Handler Html
getPageR = do
  ((_, widget), enctype') <- runFormGet userForm
  defaultLayout [whamlet|
                 <form method=post action=@{PageR} enctype=#{enctype'}>
                 ^{widget} -- This widget include.
                 <button>Submit|]
```

But how can I rewrite it without hamlet? My current code is like this:

```
getPageR = do
  ((_, widget), enctype') <- runFormGet userForm
  defaultLayout $ do
    toWidgetBody $ \render -> do
      H.div ! A.id "form" $ do
        H.form ! A.method "post" ! A.action (action' render) ! A.enctype (enct' enctype) $ ""
        -- widget include?
        H.button "Submit!"
   where
     action' = \render -> toValue $! render (PageR) []
     enct'   = toValue . renderHtml . toHtml
```

Obvously, type of the blaze code is Html, but userForm type is a Widget, so it cannot be connected. I can only add widget after `toWidgetBody` function, but then form will be after all content. Is there a way to include forms within blaze combinators(by rendering it to Html, maybe?) without hamlet `^{widget}` construct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`widgetToPageContent`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.23/docs/Yesod-Core.html#v:widgetToPageContent) function.

You then get at the `Html` by calling [`pageBody`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.23/docs/Yesod-Core-Types.html#t:PageContent) and applying the `render` function.

```
getPageR :: Handler Html -- same as: HandlerT App IO Html
getPageR = do
  ((_, widget), enctype') <- runFormGet sampleForm
  content <- widgetToPageContent widget
  defaultLayout $ do
    toWidgetBody $ \render -> do
      H.div ! A.id "form" $ do
        H.form ! A.method "post" ! A.action (action' render)
                                 ! A.enctype (enct' enctype') $ ""
        pageBody content render
        H.button "Submit!"
   where
     action' = \render -> toValue $! render (PageR) []
     enct'   = toValue . renderHtml . toHtml
     (!) = (H.!)
     toValue = H.toValue
```

Comment: If I want to use a monadic form instead of applicative, is it possible to expand FieldView to Html there too to use it in a widget definition?

Comment: Please open up a new question for this with the appropriate code example - thanks.